# cannot find symbol class AccessFragmentInternals

Tags: android, android-support-library

In my project i want to import `android.support.v4.app.AccessFragmentInternals`, after some googleing about this problem i found which i must to add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

to my app `build.gradle`, after sync project i have this problem too, clean project and rebuild project couldn't resolve my problem and removing libraries folder from `.idea/` too

how can i resolve this problem and can be use this support library?

my Gradle content

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK named `AccessFragmentInternals`, including in the support libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare i added this line: `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`

Comment: So? You are similarly welcome to add `import android.support.v4.app.ThisClassNameIsFake`, and you will not find it either. **There is no such class in the Android SDK**.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok. so which support libraries must be added to project? i updated my post

Comment: None. **There is no such class in the Android SDK**. If you want a class with that name, write it yourself.